# Generating prefix bitmasks

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, undefined-behavior, branchless

I am looking for a portable way to generate *prefix bitmasks* which have the first `n` bits set for `0 <= n <= 32` (or 64 or an arbitrary integer type bit width).

Examples:

```
prefix_bitmask(0)  = 0b00000000000000000000000000000000u
prefix_bitmask(4)  = 0b00000000000000000000000000001111u
prefix_bitmask(32) = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111u
```

There are two ways this can already work if we ignore the cases `n == 0` or `n == 32`:

```cpp
// "constructive": set only the required bits
uint32_t prefix_mask1(int i) { return (uint32_t(1) << i) - 1; }
// "destructive": shift unneeded bits out
uint32_t prefix_mask2(int i) { return ~uint32_t(0) >> (32 - i); }
```

`prefix_mask1` fails for 32 and `prefix_mask2` fails for 0, both because shifts larger than the integer type are undefined behavior (because CPUs are allowed to only use the lowest 5 bits of the shift size).

Is there a "canonical" way to solve this without branching?

Comment: `((unit32_t)(-1)) >> (32-i)`

Comment: That's prefix_mask2 in disguise. I just like using ~0 instead of -1.

Comment: `32` is not larger than the integer type. Is this because of your 5-bit rule? Yeah, I get it, the 32-bit shift *doesn't* work. It has the same effect as `>> 0` but is perhaps undefined.

Comment: shifting a 32-bit integer by 32 is undefined behavior. I think the reason for this is that there are two ways a processor could execute such a shift: Set the result to 0 or don't shift at all. That's what I mean by the 5-bit thing ;)

Comment: fwiw, undefined behavior does not mean "there are two ways to get the same result", rather "there are arbitrary ways to get an arbitrary result" ;)

Comment: I am aware, I was mainly trying to reason *why* out-of-bounds shifts are most likely declared undefined behavior based on the underlying machine architectures ;)

Comment: They are undefined behaviour *for the purposes of the C standard*. It does not mean you can't define what will happen in practice on any given architecture.

Comment: @TobiasRibizel If the standard defined the behavior, then the code sequences emitted for every variable length bit-shift operation would need extra code to deal with the special cases where behavior of the CPU's bit-shift instructions do not match the C standard definition.

Comment: @IanAbbott: If the Standard were to specify that `x>>bitSize` may behave as an unspecified choice between `x` and `x>>(bitSize-1)>>1`, in how many non-contrived scenarios would impair efficient code generation?  There are a fair number of situations where both results would be equally useful (e.g. `(x<<y) | (x >> (32-y))`), and requiring that programmers guard against an attempted shift by 32 in such cases doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`((uint32_t) 1 << i/2 << i-i/2) - 1`.

The above works where `uint32_t` may be replaced with any unsigned type, and no other changes are needed. Other options that require knowing the number of bits `b` in the type and a mask `m` = 2<sup>`b`</sup>−1 include:

`((uint32_t) 1 << (i & m)) - 1 - (i >> b)` (from [supercat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363751/supercat))

and:

`((uint32_t) i >> b) ^ 1) << (i & m)) - 1` (derived from a suggestion by [Matt Timmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483526/matt-timmermans)).

Comment: Any half-decent optimizer will figure this out.

Comment: @MSalters: Figure what out? Do you mean it will recognize it is equivalent to `1 << i` except that it is defined when `i` is the width of the type and then implement optimal code for that? What does optimal code look like if the machine does not have an instruction that implements a shift for the full width? A conditional move or branch after testing `i`, two shifts as written, or something else?

Comment: That you're really trying to do `<<i`, but with the appropriate zeroing semantics for `<<32`.

Comment: @MSalters neither clang 10 nor gcc 10.1 [figure it out](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oaeH6v), but I'm OK with saying they're less than half-decent compilers

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'd guess that a literal translation of `(1u << (i & 31)) - 1 - (i >> 5)` would probably work decently for values of i from 0 to 32, inclusive.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the `prefix_mask2` idea with arithmetic shifts to prepare the correct pattern, with three instructions total (assuming shift counts in the CPU are modulo word width):

```
// minimal instruction dependency (2 cycles), but requires large constant
// that some architectures have trouble generating
uint32_t prefix_mask2a(int i) {
    return ((int32_t) (i + (0x80000000 - 32))) >> ((i ^ 31) & 31);
}

// 3 cycles
uint32_t prefix_mask2b(int i) {
    return (uint32_t) ((int32_t) -i >> 31) >> (-i & 31);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cast `uint32_t` to something with more bits, shift that, and then convert back:

```
uint32_t prefix_mask(int i) {
  return UINT32_MAX & ((UINT64_C(1) << i) - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is quite portable

```
#define PREFIX(type, n) (type)(((sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT - (n)) == sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT) ? ((type)0) : (!(sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT - (n)) ? (~(type)(0)) : ((~(type)(0)) << (sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT - n))))
#define POSTFIX(type, n) (type)(((sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT - (n)) == sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT) ? ((type)0) : (!(sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT - (n)) ? (~(type)(0)) : ((~(type)(0)) >> (sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT - n))))

#define TEST_TYPE unsigned long long

void printbin(TEST_TYPE x)
{
    TEST_TYPE mask = (TEST_TYPE)1 << (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
    while(mask)
    {
        printf("%d", !!(x & mask));
        mask >>= 1;
    }
}


int main()
{
    for(int x = 0; x <= sizeof(TEST_TYPE) * CHAR_BIT; x++)
    {
        printbin(PREFIX(TEST_TYPE, x)); printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int x = 0; x <= sizeof(TEST_TYPE) * CHAR_BIT; x++)
    {
        printbin(POSTFIX(TEST_TYPE, x)); printf("\n");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/_NadkH

Comment: I think you missed one important point in OP's question: *"Is there a "canonical" way to solve this **without branching**"*